# How to group the rows based on parent node in table in ASP.NET MVC using C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This screenshot shows that currently my records are displayed in separate rows even if the date is the same:

[image]

My expectation is this:

[image]

I'm simply iterating using a `foreach` loop on the list.

Can someone please guide me here, how to group by the date column and display the child rows under that date in single parent row?

```
 foreach (var CustbookingDet in Model.ListBookingdtl)
 {
     <tr no="1" id="tr_1" class="parentRow">
         <td>
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon add clsParentAddBtn" id="btnParentAddID"><img src="../images/add.svg"></a>
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon clsParentDeleteBtn" id="btnParentDeleteID"><img src="../images/delete.svg"></a>
         </td>
         <td>

             <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="input-group date" id="bs_datepicker_component_container1">
                     <div class="form-line">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @CustbookingDet.DateTime, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @id = "date" })
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bookingdate, null, new { @class = "error", @id = "valdate" })
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="childRow">
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon add clsChildAddBtn" id="btnChildAddID"><img src="../images/add.svg"></a>
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon clsChildDeleteBtn" id="btnChildDeleteID"><img src="../images/delete.svg"></a>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="icons" id="FunctionContainers">
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => @CustbookingDet.FunctionIDs, new SelectList(Model.DropdownFunctions, "Value", "Text", @CustbookingDet.FunctionIDs), "-- Select function --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick", id = "FunctionItemIds" })
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FunctionIDs, null, new { @class = "error", @id = "valfunction" })
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="icons" id="ServiceContainers">
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => @CustbookingDet.ServiceId, new SelectList(Model.DropdownServices, "Value", "Text", @CustbookingDet.ServiceId), "-- Select Services --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick", id = "ServiceItemIds" })
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceIds, null, new { @class = "error", @id = "valservices" })
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="icons" id="AssigntoContainers">
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => @CustbookingDet.VendorId, new SelectList(Model.DropdownAssign, "Value", "Text", @CustbookingDet.ServiceId), "-- Select AssignTo --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick", id = "AssignItemIds" })
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Assignperson, null, new { @class = "error", @id = "valvendor" })
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div id="RateContainers" class="form-group">
                 <div class="form-line">
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @CustbookingDet.Rate, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtRates" })
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rate, null, new { @class = "error", @id = "valrates" })
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`GroupBy` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-8.0) in LINQ.

**.cshtml.cs**

In the `OnGet` method of the Razor page's `.cshtml.cs` file, group the booking list `ListBookingdtl` by the `DateTime` property.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, BookingModel>> GroupedBookingList = ListBookingdtl.GroupBy(b => b.DateTime);
```

Set the grouped booking list to a page model property like you did for `ListBookingdtl`.

**.cshtml**

The `foreach` loop in the Razor page view would be modified to loop through the date groups. After the HTML for the parent row, add another `foreach` loop to add a child row for each item within the date group.

Access the date in each group using `dateTimeGroup.Key` or access the first entry in a group (e.g. `dateTimeGroup[0].DateTimeProperty`).

```
@foreach (IGrouping<DateTime, BookingModel> dateTimeGroup in Model.GroupedBookingList)
{
    <tr no="1" id="tr_1" class="parentRow">
        ...
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="bs_datepicker_component_container1">
                     <div class="form-line">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => @dateTimeGroup[0].DateTime, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @id = "date" })
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bookingdate, null, new { @class = "error", @id = "valdate" })
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    @foreach (BookingModel CustbookingDet in dateTimeGroup)
    {
        <tr class="childRow">
            ...
        </tr>
    }
}
```